# Python: binary vector

Tags: python-2.7, vector

I have a set of indices:

```
indices = (['1', '1.2', '2', '2.2', '3', '4'])
```

and a dataset, where the first element identifies a person, the second a round, and the third is the index from the indices set:

```
dataset = [['A', '1', '1'], ['A', '1', '1.2'], ['B', '1', '2'], ['C', '2', '3']]
```

I would like to form a binary vector, where for each person and for each individual round, the indices are marked either present (with a 1) or not (with a 0).

The desired output would be something like so, where for A, the vector represents the presence of the indices 1 and 1.2, for B, the index 2, and for C, the index 3. Note that for A, there is only one record, but 2 indices are present.

```
['A', '1', '1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0']
['B', '1', '0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0']
['C', '2', '0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0']
```

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my head around the looping of the indices over the dataset. My idea was to loop through the indices set the same amount of time as the number of lists in the dataset. But I dont think this is the most efficient way, and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use pandas dataframe for this, first merge two dataframes by indices then a oneHotShot.

Comment: @anishtain4 could you show an example of this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it something like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

for k, g in groupby(dataset, lambda x: x[:2]):
    vals = [x[2] for x in g]
    print(k + [", ".join("1" if x in vals else "0" for x in indices)])
```

Output

```
['A', '1', '1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0']
['B', '1', '0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0']
['C', '2', '0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0']
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without loops

```
import pandas as pd
indlist=['1', '1.2', '2', '2.2', '3', '4']
dataset = [['A', '1', '1'], ['A', '1', '1.2'], ['B', '1', '2'], ['C', '2', '3']]
df=pd.DataFrame(dataset,columns=['player','round','ind']).set_index('ind').reindex(indlist)
ans=df.reset_index().pivot('player','ind','round').fillna(0)[1:]
```